# MKV Web Player (Not npapi)

Tags: html, video, web, mkv

Is there any way to play a MKV video on browser (Chrome and Mozilla Firefox) ? **Native HTML5 Video Player** plays back the video but no audio and **Divx Web Player** became obsolete since Chrome 45.

Any and all help appreciated :)

Comment: you'll either have to transcode and switch the container to mp4 or use the EME capabilities in javascript to process the frames and feed them to the buffer (I've seen examples for DASH but not re-containerization)